# PhoneStateListener onCallStateChanged method params "incoming number" empty in Android 9.0?

Tags: android, phone-state-listener

> ```
> @Override
> public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {
>     super.onCallStateChanged(state, incomingNumber);
>     switch (state) {
>         case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
>             if (incomingNumber == null || "".equals(incomingNumber)) {
>                 return;
>             }
>             break;
>     }
> }
> ```

I got same issue  below Android sdk27 ever,  I  start PhoneStateListener in PhoneService ,

> ```
> public  void startPhoneStateListener() {
>     mTelManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
>     mTelManager.listen(mPhoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
> }
> ```

but I  only start Service in RootReceiver, not in MainActivity ,when I start PhoneService in MainActivity ,I fixed it.

```
  <receiver android:name=".receiver.RootReceiver">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

but  this only work below Android sdk 27 , I  have  no  idea  about Android 9.0  , by the way,  I  have  written the  permission  :

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per the [Behavior Changes for all apps in Android 9.0](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/pie/android-9.0-changes-all#restrict-access-phone-numbers):

> Phone numbers associated with incoming and outgoing calls are visible in the [phone state broadcast](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#action_phone_state_changed), such as for incoming and outgoing calls and are accessible from the [`PhoneStateListener`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/PhoneStateListener) class. Without the [`READ_CALL_LOG`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission#READ_CALL_LOG) permission, however, the phone number field that's provided in `PHONE_STATE_CHANGED` broadcasts and through `PhoneStateListener` is empty.

You must request the `READ_CALL_LOG` permission if you want the incoming phone number.

Note that as per that same page:

> To read numbers from `onCallStateChanged()`, you need the `READ_CALL_LOG` permission only. You don't need the `READ_PHONE_STATE` permission.

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CALL_LOG"/>
I added it  into mainfest, things  havenot changed.

Comment: It is a runtime permission, so make sure you are requesting it at runtime.

Comment: If this helped answer the question, please make sure to accept the answer to remove this question from the unanswered queue of questions. Best of luck!

Comment: how  can i  do it?

Comment: @ianhanniballake but as per google permission rules read call log permission was deprecated from March 31. So if you have another solution let me know.

Comment: I have already added read_call_log permission, yet I am getting empty string for phone number. Can anyone help me with this.

Comment: @AmitChauhan - keep in mind that `READ_CALL_LOG` is a dangerous permission that you need to request at runtime - having it in your manifest isn't enough

Comment: It is working after asking for READ_CALL_LOG permission at runtime. Thanks.

Comment: Any other way to get phone number without using READ_CALL_LOG. As it is very difficult to publish this app with READ_CALL_LOG persmission on playstore